# Magento events not firing on full page cache

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I'm using Amasty Full Page Cache for Magento 1.x

When inspecting the events that get fired when page cache is hit, i found that resource_get_tablename and http_response_send_before are the only 2 events that are fired during cache hit.

However attaching an observer to http_response_send_before doesn't do anything when cache is hit.

I looked into dispatchEvent function of Mage_Core_Model_App and found out that $this->_events is empty when cache is hit, so is there any way to attach an observer to any kinds of events? I'm adding some tracking and don't want to modify index.php

Answer (score 1):

**`controller_front_send_response_before`**

This event will be fired irrespective of FPC enabled. Try using observer with this one